# How to submit form after ajax test without getting XSS error?

Tags: jquery, json, forms, xss, getjson

After a user completes and attempts to submit a form, I'd like to query the server to see whether the user is authenticated. If not, I'd like to pop up a login window which will be closed after logging in leaving the form data undisturbed and ready for submission.

The problem is that, if the user is logged in, I want to call form.submit(), but since that is from a callback, it gives an XSS error. Is there a better way? Here is what I have tried:

```
function submitForm(form) { form.submit();}

$("#myForm").submit(function () {
                     var thisForm = this;
                     $.getJSON("/url/login_check/", function(data) {
                           if (data.loggedIn === true) { 
                               submitForm(thisForm); 
                            }
                            else {
                               // display login popup
                            }
                     });
                     return false;
  });
```

Comment: what are you calling an xss error ?

Comment: My browser shows this message: 403 Forbidden

Cross Site Request Forgery detected. Request aborted.

Comment: what server side stack are you using?  This sounds fishy -- you shouldn't need to explicitly make a call to check log in status.

Comment: django. I am doing authentication on the server, but if the session times out after the user has entered form data and then POSTs it, the data is gone. I think that popping up a log in window while not changing the original form with its data is a better user experience.

Comment: Mitch; it might be simpler to simply capture the form contents and repopulate the form after the user has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an XSS error because you're trying to send a JSON request to a different domain which you cannot do.

What you probably need to do is to send a JSONP request (assuming your authentication server supports them). This allows you to send data to a remote domain and process the response.

Comment: That's what I thought. An unappealing alternative might be to make a synchronous query to the server. Also, doesn't JSONP only work for GETs?

Comment: If you're doing authentication, then a GET is the appropriate verb. POST only makes sense if there is a corresponding change to server state.
Also, it doesn't matter if the query is synchronous or not... if it's to a different domain as the one serving your code, then you're attempting XSS

Comment: You're right about the GET. I was confusing the authentication request with the POST of the form. But the domain of the form and the getJSON request are the same - the getJSOn function should just be submitting a form from the same page it is on. So I don't see where the different domains are.

Comment: I think the XSS error might be due to logging in from the popup window and not due to submitting the form from the getJSON function.